# Display detail related to variation in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to display details related to variation but I don't have an idea of how to do that. Please help me. View JSON response [here](https://ibb.co/m9w8MC0).

[image]

**Model**

```
public function variationDetail()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\VariationDetail',
        'product_variation', 'product_id', 'variation_detail_id');
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function productDetails($productId)
{
    $data = [
        'productDetails' => Product::with('variationDetail', 'productColorGallery')
            ->where('id', $productId)->first(),
        'variations' => Variation::orderBy('sort')->get()
    ];
    // return $data['productDetails'];

    return view('products-detail', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($variations as $value)
<li>
    <div class="prodHeading">
        <h6>
            {{$value->name}} :
        </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="prodDecp">
        <p>Red , Blue , green</p>
    </div>
</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What is the issue here? Does $variations array prints values?

Comment: yes please check https://ibb.co/NrpMDcF

Comment: Your output has an array with a name which is color, but there are no values associated with the color. You need to fetch those details from the database, check what other tables are used to save those details.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($variations as $value)
<li>
<div class="prodHeading">
    <h6>
        {{$value->name}} :
    </h6>
</div>
<div class="prodDecp">
    <p> @foreach ($productColorGallery as $value_color) {{ $value_color }}, 
@endforeach</p>
</div>
<div class="prodDecp">
    <p> @foreach ($variationDetailas $value_details) {{ $value_details}}, 
@endforeach</p>
</div>
</li>
@endforeach
```

you can fetch your data like this i hope you got your solution .